# Asterisk Background music with ChanSpy()

Tags: asterisk

I want to inject background music while my EAGI script is running.
I`ve found out how to do it, using ChanSpy().

So, I wrote this context in my dialplan.

```
[test]
exten => 1,1,originate(Local/1@music,app,playback,<path_to_audio>)
exten => 1,n,Set(fname=${UNIQUEID})
exten => 1,n,MixMonitor(/records/${fname}.wav)
exten => 1,n,EAGI(<path_to_script>)

[music]
exten => 1,1,Answer()
exten => 1,n,ChanSpy(SIP/<channel>, qsW)
```

I expected I`ll be listening background audio during the whole call, but I hear my audio only when Playback() in my EAGI script is executing. When I capture inbound audiostream in EAGI I still hear nothing, but silence. How could I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Use conference call, will be always

Or use your EAGI in ChanSpy, not music.

Issue is becuase of audiohooks, it is complex to describe why.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I`ve tried to use EAGI in ChanSpy, but now EAGI script is executing on local channel, not on SIP peer. How could I do it properly? Can I just define specific channel for my EAGI script?

Comment: No, you can't. You can do own function in c/c++, as example see func_volume.c or func_pitch.c